# Using jQuery css to change color produced by autofill

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use jQuery's css function to change the color of my email input box

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="" id="duplicate_email" />
```

Just changing the color as in

```
jQuery('#duplicate_email').css('color', 'red', 'important');
```

does not work as the autofill takes precedence

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}
```

I have tried to turn the autocomplete off, but this no longer works in chrome

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="" id="duplicate_email" autocomplete="off" />
```

I saw in the jQuery documentation

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .css() setter will automatically take care of prefixing the property name. For example, take .css( "user-select", "none" ) in Chrome/Safari will set it as -webkit-user-select, Firefox will use -moz-user-select, and IE10 will use -ms-user-select.

so I tried this

```
jQuery('input["email"]:-webkit-autofill').css('text-fill-color', 'red !important');
```

but go no where.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Never dabbled against autocomplete, but you could try toggling a class to see if that over rides it

Comment: I would just make another class, and add that class using jQuery instead of modifying the css. it makes it much cleaner and more maintainable

Comment: My experience has been that the autofill takes precedence and overrides anything I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried modifying the CSS of the autofill using CSS instead of jQuery?

```css
#MyInput:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  color: black;
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='Autofill Me' id='MyInput' />
```

If you want to use jQuery to target the elements to change just do this in the CSS with a specific class name and then assign that specific class name to the elements your jQuery selects.

```js
$("#duplicate_email").addClass("Alternative-Autofill");
```

```css
.Alternative-Autofill:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Yes, and this works. I am using the `.css` function because I want to change the color of the email input under certain criteria.

Comment: Then just use jQuery to give the inputs that meet the certain criteria a special class name and then access that like this.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: It was the second half of your solution that did the trick for me. Very clever solution. Thank you.